# Security proof of this paper(Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption) which proposes the first CP-ABE scheme

Tags: encryption, public-key, abe

I have trouble in understanding the security proof of this paper([Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption](https://doi.org/10.1109/SP.2007.11))

[image: the defintion of two games]

[image: two hybrids]

why are these two hybrids equivalent to the modified game above? It is obvious that $M_0e(g, g)^{\alpha s}$ and $e(g, g)^{\alpha s}$ are not euqal.